# Trying to recreate the strcpy function using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to learn pointer by recreating the `strcpy` function in C. It stopped working whenever I have space, tab in my input string (anything other than an English character).

Could anyone explain to be why?
All answers are appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strcpys(char *s, char *t);
int main() {
    char *ms;
    char *mt;

    mt = "ABCDEFGAAA,AAAAA";
    strcpys(ms, mt);
    printf("%s\n", ms);
    printf("%s\n", mt);
    return 0;
}

void strcpys(char *s, char *t) {
    while ((*s = *t) != '\0') {
        s++;
        t++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "stopped working"-- you should include more explicit inputs and outputs and errors/etc.

Comment: Worth noting here that your destination string (`ms`) is a pointer to apparently unallocated memory, so you're copying bytes into.. somewhere. (Which isn't what you want to be doing.)

Comment: You didn't allocate any memory for `ms` and it is uninitialized. So this is undefined behavior.

Comment: After you fix that problem, consider this version: `void strcpys(char *dest, char *src) { while (*dest++ = *src++){} }`. It's one of the classic examples of how concise C can be, for better or worse.

Comment: @Shawn even more concise `void strcpys(char *dest, char *src) { while (*dest++ = *src++); }` one byte shorter :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `strcpys` function is OK, but the `main` function a problem:

- the destination argument passed to `strcpys` is an uninitialized pointer. This has undefined behavior, quite likely a segmentation fault. You should instead pass a pinter to a `char` large enough to hold all characters from the source plus a null byte terminator.

Here are some possible improvements too:

- `strcpys` should return the destination pointer
- the source pointer should be declared as `const char *`
- the argument names should be less confusing

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char *strcpys(char *dest, const char *src);

int main() {
    char ms[32];
    const char *mt = "ABCDEFGAAA,AAAAA";
    strcpys(ms, mt);
    printf("%s\n", ms);
    printf("%s\n", mt);
    return 0;
}

char *strcpys(char *dest, const char *src) {
    char *p = dest;
    while ((*p = *src) != '\0') {
        p++;
        src++;
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Note that you can combine the increments into the assignment:

```c
char *strcpys(char *dest, const char *src) {
    char *p = dest;
    while ((*p++ = *src++) != '\0')
        continue;
    return dest;
}
```

Note that both versions have undefined behavior if the destination pointer points inside the source string. The functions behave as expected if the destination array and source do not overlap or if the destination is at a lower address than the source string. The standard `strcpy` function has undefined behavior if the source and destination arrays overlap.

Comment: @bruno: this explicit `continue;` statement is my style. I **definitely** do **not** want to use an empty statement as in `while ((*p++ = *src++) != '\0');` and I don't particularly like the empty block `{}` either, especially with the K&R bracing style. The explicit `continue;` tells the reader unambiguously that the body is purposely empty. Of course all three generate the same code.

Comment: You can simplify further into `for (char* p = dest; *p++ = *src++;); return dest;`.

Comment: @L.F.: indeed, even more characters can be removed from the source code: `char*strcpys(char*a,const char*b){for(char*c=a;*c++=*b++;);return a;}` generates the same code, but is much less readable :)

Comment: With the caveat that the strings cannot overlap, otherwise you would need to get the length and copy from the end to the beginning (as with `memmove`).